# IEx - bash like autocompletion for file paths

Tags: elixir

IEx autocompletion works fine with modules and functions. I wonder if it is possible to get autocomplete for paths in IEx helper functions (c, cd, ...) for instance:

```
iex(1)> import_file("file<TAB-key>
```

Answer (score 1):

In bash, most commands follow the pattern of "command options path", so it is obvious, that autocomplete should search the paths, because of the context. `import_file` is a function, that takes string as an argument. IEx doesn't know, if it is path-string or some other string, so it would be hard to write autocompletion.

It is not impossible, but I don't think anyone went through the pain of doing it, when you can simply type the path in bash with autocomplete and then copy-paste it :)